# Is it possible to set innodb_stats_on_metadata in PHP PDO prepare statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb, prepare

I transfer part of MySQL database from one server to another using XML. In this XML I have all DB related information I need (data & metadata). Everything works fine except one thing – **obtaining foreign key constraints from [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-information-schema-overview.html)**.

The problem lies in **performance**. Getting approximately 100 constraints takes up about 7 minutes of PHP script loading! However, if one runs command

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
```

with constraint query (i.e. in PHPMyAdmin) like this

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

everything takes up about 5 seconds and it's done. Now, this is a huge timesaver and it would be really great if I could use this in following fashion:

```
         try{
                $conn = $this->db->_pdo;
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 0); //disable autocommit for transaction consistency
                $conn->beginTransaction();

                $this->db->_pdo->exec('SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0');
                
                $query = $this->db->_pdo->prepare('
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                    WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = ?');
                $query->bindParam(1, $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $keys = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $conn->commit();
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 1);

                if(!empty($keys)) return $keys; else return false;
        }catch (Exception $e){
                $conn->rollback();
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                return false;
        }
```

The problem is that exec command is just ignored here and process time is still very long. If I put that command into prepare (before SELECT and separated by semicolon) everything just ends with an error.

So my question is: **How can I set mysqli DB parameter innodb_stats_on_metadata inside PHP PDO structure which uses transactions and prepare statements?**

Comment: the only cause for the statement to be "ignored" is an error in it

Comment: why you're trying to set it **GLOBAL**?

Comment: I don't really have much experience in this MySQL commands field. The exec finishes fine (I checked it for error, non was thrown). But still it doesn't take effect.
As to your second question, could you please give me a hint of how to set it better then globally?

Comment: set it for the session. means without word 'global'

Comment: Wow, it works!! I removed the GLOBAL and the execution time is now under 1 second. I never would have thought that it would be that simple :) ... Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems strange to me that no exception were thrown. Did you set your PDO in exception mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove word GLOBAL from the statement. It surely won't let to set GLOBAL state variable for user without root privileges.

Comment: Well I got a little too exited yesterday and didn't notice that there was an error in my log: `Caught exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1229 Variable 'innodb_stats_on_metadata' is a GLOBAL variable and should be set with SET GLOBAL` ... Do you please have any suggestions?

Comment: Well. If, as you said, the execution time is now under 1 second - just get rid of this line at all.

Comment: Weeell, funny story, it ended with an error and showed last valid output thus extremely shortening the time of execution (duh). Also **I don't believe there is a way out of this problem if we stuck on using information_schema**. Obviously 3rd party operations with this element are extremely time consuming. I think I better get constraints using `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` and [regex](http://us2.php.net/preg_match). Thank you very much for your help though!